# JQuery not creating object using $('#22/1')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery and have element in DOM with `id="22/1"`. When I try to create object by id in jQuery using `$('#22/1')` I am getting below error.

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #22/1
>           at Function.ga.error (jquery.min.js:2)
>           at ga.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
>           at ga.select (jquery.min.js:2)
>           at Function.ga [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
>           at r.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
>           at new r.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
>           at r (jquery.min.js:2)
>           at :1:1

So how do I can get element using jQuery? is this a but in jQuery?
Please dont suggest to use `$(document.getElementById('22/1'))`.

Comment: You need to escape the `/`: `$('#22\\/1')`

Comment: So how are you reading them? Assuming you're building a string selector, use `replace()`: `selectorreplace(/\//g, '\\\\/');` http://jsfiddle.net/be1n2fck/

Comment: yes this can work. and I'll have to modify lots of code for this. 
BTW I am not reading element by hard coding in jQuery.
here is how I am getting id
var val = $('#myDropDown').dropdown('get value');
var dataList =  $('#some_prefix_id_'+val).data('some_data');
I belive the # symbole is to refere the elements id (http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Its also weird that if  Html and most basic JS supports e.g. getElementById('22/1'). why escape char is required in jQuery while # is prefixed.

Comment: jQuery also not supporting $('#this.this') !!

Comment: Yes it does. If it doesnt work for you then youve done something wrong. Check the console for errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ID is somewhat pretty weird.

To access your object, use jQuery attribute selector `[...]` :

```js
let object = $('[id="22/1"]')
console.log(object[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="22/1"></div>
```

Comment: While this works, escaping the selector is more performant.

Comment: I upvoted for _Your ID is somewhat pretty weird._

Comment: Yes the ID is somewhat pretty weird.but I don't have control on it. its dynamically generated and cannot change the process.